# Overriding third party JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

We use a 3rd party control suite which has a JQuery global `ajaxError` event which we would like to customize. We don't want to update this JS file but want to somehow override it so that JQuery doesn't execute this event.

Is this possible?

EDIT: Third Party Code

```
    ajaxError: function (element, eventName, xhr, status) {
        var prevented = this.trigger(element, eventName,
            {
                XMLHttpRequest: xhr,
                textStatus: status
            });

        if (!prevented) {
            if (status == 'error' && xhr.status != '0')
                alert('Error! The requested URL returned ' + xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText);
            if (status == 'timeout')
                alert('Error! Server timeout.');
        }
    }
```

I wan to nullify the line starting from the if condition

Comment: How is it bound?  Could you give the code you want to nullify?

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the whole method but not only a single statement.

**EDIT**:
<strike>The library you're using is built using prototypes I guess.</strike> Just noticed you're using jQuery. Therefore you might use jQuery.fn instead of LibName.prototype. Overwriting it would look similar to:

```
jQuery.fn.ajaxError = function(element, eventName, xhr, status) {
  var prevented = this.trigger(element, eventName,
  {
    XMLHttpRequest: xhr,
    textStatus: status
  });
}
```

Comment: How do I override the whole method in JS and how would I handle the trigger call?

Comment: My understanding is that the fn syntax is used to add functionality to jquery (creating plugins). Does this work for overriding jquery methods as well?

Comment: if `ajaxError` is defined in the context of `fn`, say as an plugin, it should. did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I did and it did not work. The 3rd party JS I am overriding is based on JQuery but since I am overriding the 3rd party JS, I can't use fn. I tried to use the prototype but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You can override any property as following:

```
    var thirdParty = {
        override: function() {                
            alert('this function should have been overridden');
        }
    };

    var thirdPartyOriginal = thirdParty.override;

    thirdParty.override = function() {
        alert('this function has been overridden');
    };

    thirdParty.override();

    thirdParty.override = thirdPartyOriginal;
```

The example show the retention of original and then after execution of new code. I return it back to original state.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyClass: MC

{
  protected override void OnError(..)
  {
     //handle error, send error to where ever
  }
}
```