# Overriding javascript built in to 3rd party control (infragistics UltraWebGrid)

Tags: javascript, overriding, infragistics

I am using an old version of `UltraWebGrid` by Infragistics and need to replace some of the built in javascript. The compiled js looks like its adding a bunch of functions to an object type as an api of sorts. formatted like:

```
var igtbl_ptsBand = ["functionname1",function(){...},"functionname2",function(){...},...
```

and so on. How would I override this?

Basically the control is adding html to the page in a way that is not compatible with newer browsers and the javascript code that does this just needs a little tweak. I found the code... I just need to change it.

The code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648655/how-to-force-a-tbody-element-into-an-empty-table-for-non-ie-browsers)

I added an answer to dump code examples in and whatnot. I will not select this answer

[Similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081687/overriding-third-party-js)

Comment: i've worked with these components before and somehow i am not suprised at the completely backasswards way they store their functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you mentioned seems to be a function table of sorts:

```
var igtbl_ptsBand = ["func1", function() { }, "func2", function() { } ]
```

I would recommend using chaining instead of just an override.  With chaining you can inject your own code, but still call the original function.  Let's say you want to replace "func2" and chain.  You could do something like this:

```
var origFunc, findex, ix;
if (igtbl_ptsBand.indexOf) {
    // indexOf is supported, use it
    findex = igtbl_ptsBand.indexOf("func2") + 1;
} else {
    // Crippled browser such as IE, no indexOf, use loop
    findex = -1;
    for (ix = 0;  ix < igtbl_ptsBand.length;  ix += 2) {
        if (igtbl_ptsBand[ix] === "func2") {
            findex = ix + 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (findex >= 0) {
    // Found it, chain
    origFunc = igtbl_ptsBand[findex];
    igtbl_ptsBand[findex] = function() {
         // Your new pre-code here
         // Call original func (chain)
         origFunc();
         // Your new post-code here
    };
}
```

origFunc may have arguments, of course, and you may want to use the JavaScript call() function to set the "this pointer" to something specific, e.g.:

```
origFunc.call(customThis, arg1, arg2...);
```

If the arguments are in an array, you can use apply() instead of call().

Comment: where do i need to put this javascript for this to work? It runs but the old javascript is still being used/

Comment: @jumpdart, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: I added an answer to explain the actions I am taking.

Comment: I added what I did above. The replacing of the function worked, but then I had to apply it to everything. Seems kind of odd, but I noticed something similar happening in the compiled JS after the first definitions were defined, so I did the same and it all works now. ~Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend doing this. You should always try to work *with* a third party library, not *against* it. That being said, this should work:

```
igtbl_ptsBand[igtbl_ptsBand.indexOf("functionYouWantToOverwrite") + 1] = function () {
    // your new stuff...
};
```

Comment: I have to fix things on the cheep and there are way too many developers that would need licenses to upgrade to the newer version of the control that actually is browser compatible, so this is my only option. Thanks BTW... checking this out now

Comment: Be careful that older versions of IE (8 or less) don't support indexOf.  You may need to use a loop if indexOf is undefined.

Comment: where do i need to put this javascript for this to work? It runs but the old javascript is still being used

Comment: @jumpdart placing it anywhere after the original function assignment should work.

Comment: Seems as if it is getting reset to its original... looking into it. I added a question to explain how i am proceeding

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is what I am doing. I will update this with my progress.

This fixes my problem. It turns out I had to apply the functionarray to all child objects of the parent "rows". To do this I added the code in my "Fix Rows" function. I split it up because i am running accross other browser JS error which I am fixing in this js file.

Here is the js file that I added to my .net page like so...

```
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../scripts/BrowserCompat.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

.

```
Brows_FixUltraWebGrid();

function Brows_FixUltraWebGrid() {
    FixRows();
}

function FixRows() {

    FixGridRows_render();
    for (var i = 0; i < igtbl_ptsRows.length; i += 2)
        igtbl_Rows.prototype[igtbl_ptsRows[i]] = igtbl_ptsRows[i + 1];

}


function FixGridRows_render() {

    var origFunc, findex, ix;
    if (igtbl_ptsRows.indexOf) {
        // indexOf is supported, use it
        findex = igtbl_ptsRows.indexOf("render") + 1;
    } else {
        // Crippled browser such as IE, no indexOf, use loop
        findex = -1;
        for (ix = 0; ix < igtbl_ptsRows.length; ix += 2) {
            if (igtbl_ptsRows[ix] === "render") {
                findex = ix + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (findex >= 0) {
        // Found it, chain
        origFunc = igtbl_ptsRows[findex];
        igtbl_ptsRows[findex] = function() {
            // Your new pre-code here
            // Call original func (chain)
            //origFunc();
            // Your new post-code here
            var strTransform = this.applyXslToNode(this.Node);
            if (strTransform) {
                var anId = (this.AddNewRow ? this.AddNewRow.Id : null);

                //new logic to include tbody if it is not there
                var tadd1 = '';
                var tadd2 = '';
                if (!(/\<tbody\>/.test(strTransform))) {
                    tadd1 = '<tbody>';
                    tadd2 = '</tbody>';
                }
                this.Grid._innerObj.innerHTML =
                    "<table style=\"table-layout:fixed;\">" + tadd1 + strTransform + tadd2 + "</table>";

                //old line
                //this.Grid._innerObj.innerHTML = "<table style=\"table-layout:fixed;\">" + strTransform + "</table>";

                var tbl = this.Element.parentNode;
                igtbl_replaceChild(tbl, this.Grid._innerObj.firstChild.firstChild, this.Element);
                igtbl_fixDOEXml();
                var _b = this.Band;
                var headerDiv = igtbl_getElementById(this.Grid.Id + "_hdiv");
                var footerDiv = igtbl_getElementById(this.Grid.Id + "_fdiv");
                if (this.AddNewRow) {
                    if (_b.Index > 0 || _b.AddNewRowView == 1 && !headerDiv || _b.AddNewRowView == 2 && !footerDiv) {
                        var anr = this.AddNewRow.Element;
                        anr.parentNode.removeChild(anr);
                        if (_b.AddNewRowView == 1 && tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length > 0)
                            tbl.tBodies[0].insertBefore(anr, tbl.tBodies[0].rows[0]);
                        else
                            tbl.tBodies[0].appendChild(anr);
                    }
                    this.AddNewRow.Element = igtbl_getElementById(anId);
                    this.AddNewRow.Element.Object = this.AddNewRow;
                }
                this.Element = tbl.tBodies[0];
                this.Element.Object = this;
                this._setupFilterRow();
                for (var i = 0; i < this.Band.Columns.length; i++) {
                    var column = this.Band.Columns[i];
                    if (column.Selected && column.hasCells()) {
                        var col = this.getColumn(i);
                        if (col)
                            igtbl_selColRI(this.Grid.Id, col, this.Band.Index, i);
                    }
                }
                if (this.ParentRow) {
                    this.ParentRow.ChildRowsCount = this.length;
                    this.ParentRow.VisChildRowsCount = this.length;
                }
            }
            console.log('overridden row render function executed');
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It's replacing the function pointer, but you really need to know if the function pointer is getting reset.  What are you using to debug?  I'd recommend console.log over alert.  You should put one inside the replacement function to see if it is getting called when it should be.