# How to override javascript library function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [Bootstrap datepicker library](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/docs/index.rst) inside my Symfony application. I would like to overwrite the function `updateNavArrows` inside `bootstrap-datepicker.js` by removing/commenting line `1132` and `1142`so the `prev` cursor which currently disappears(when I am on the page with the `startDate` as today) will always be present. Is there a better way of achieving this without having to modify the original source code?

P.S: I tried to implement the changes using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081687/overriding-third-party-js) but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js#L1123-L1163) they just remove or add a `disabled` class to the `next` and `prev` buttons

```
this.picker.find('.prev').toggleClass('disabled', prevState);
this.picker.find('.next').toggleClass('disabled', nextState);
```

this `disabled` class just puts the visibility of the button to hidden as you can see [here](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/less/datepicker.less#L192-L196)

```
.prev, .next {
    &.disabled {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

so overriding the css style to set `visibility:visible` should work

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something like this before, hope this will help you.

```
var RealupdateNavArrows = updateNavArrows;
    updateNavArrows = function() {
         alert("function overrided");
         return RealupdateNavArrows();
    }
```